# SSRS Data Driven Subscription Multiple reports running concurrently

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, business-intelligence

We have a 2010 BI Sharepoint (SSRS 2012) site that has links to several databases:

```
Database A will be available @12:00am
Database B will be available @1:00am
Database B will be available @2:00am
```

So I have a shared schedule setup for each database for the above times. How many reports should I have running in each shared schedule? For now I only have 10 sample reports and they all kicked off and ran within the same second (maybe some kicked off a couple seconds later). But I infer from that they don't run in order, rather asynchronously.

So, what is the limit and will it kill my server's performance if I have 100's of reports running. Or should I make a schedule and limit each schedule to run about 30-40 reports each?

Comment: This is something you're going to need to determine yourself - performance is going to depend heavily on the efficiency of your queries, the structure of your database, and the underlying hardware.  Generally speaking, you'll want to stagger your reports, but it's going to be up to you to determine what that frequency is going to be.  You can use the ExecutionLogStorage table in the ReportServer database to check up on run times - analyze that information to determine what's happening in your environment, and make decisions from there.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That's what I was thinking, but was hoping SSRS had some logic to not kick off all reports at once. But We'll just have to play with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not infer from your question if you are creating a snapshot or an email service...in any case there are tools that you can use to fine tune scheduling outside of ssrs. In ssrs I would recommend that you stager your report requests, if is makes sense for huge reports. In any case, You should stager your schedules to some degree.

Comment: It's an email service, and we will stager the reports as you and @kyzen recommended.